# What does -e mean in an if statement?

Tags: perl

I found the following in some Perl code:

```
if (! -e $options{"inPath"}){
       $logger->fatal("Directory \'$options{\"inPath\"}\' does not exist.\n");
}
```

What does the `-e` in the `if` statement do?

Comment: `perldoc -f -e`. It's something Perl inherited from `bash`.

Comment: Note that the error being logged (does not exist) is potentially incorrect. `$!` contains the actual error. For example, you might not have sufficient permissions to check if it exists or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Perl file tests](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) in the [online perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html) documentation site. `-e '/foo'` returns true if the file `/foo` exists.

You can access it also from the command line if you have perldoc installed in your system.

```
perldoc -f -X
```

Comment: `perldoc -f -e` works as well.

Answer (score 5):

The [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/) `unary` operator `-e`  checks if a file exists.

---

**Perldoc unary file test operators list:**

```
    -r  File is readable by effective uid/gid.
    -w  File is writable by effective uid/gid.
    -x  File is executable by effective uid/gid.
    -o  File is owned by effective uid.
    -R  File is readable by real uid/gid.
    -W  File is writable by real uid/gid.
    -X  File is executable by real uid/gid.
    -O  File is owned by real uid.
    -e  File exists.
    -z  File has zero size (is empty).
    -s  File has nonzero size (returns size in bytes).
    -f  File is a plain file.
    -d  File is a directory.
    -l  File is a symbolic link (false if symlinks aren't
        supported by the file system).
    -p  File is a named pipe (FIFO), or Filehandle is a pipe.
    -S  File is a socket.
    -b  File is a block special file.
    -c  File is a character special file.
    -t  Filehandle is opened to a tty.
    -u  File has setuid bit set.
    -g  File has setgid bit set.
    -k  File has sticky bit set.
    -T  File is an ASCII or UTF-8 text file (heuristic guess).
    -B  File is a "binary" file (opposite of -T).
    -M  Script start time minus file modification time, in days.
    -A  Same for access time.
    -C  Same for inode change time (Unix, may differ for other
    platforms)
```